# Laravel Create a new table entry while updating a column in another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a new record in one table while updating a specific column in another table. One table is users, the other table is assigned_units.

This is the AssignedUnitController for store

```
public function store(AssignUnitRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        //validate data
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $data['tenant_id'] = $request->get('tenant_id');
        $data['prop_id'] = $request->get('prop_id');
        $data['unit_id'] = $request->get('unit_id');
        $data['billing'] = $request->get('billing');
        $datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$data['start_date']);
        $data['start_date'] = $datetime;

        AssignedUnit::create(
            $data
        );

        if ($validated = $request->validated()) {
            Session::flash('success', 'Unit is successfully assigned');
            return redirect()->route('admin.tenants.index');
        }
        else {
            return back();
            Session::flash('error_message', 'Unit is not assigned');
        }
    }
}
```

This is the assigned controller for create

```
$data['tenant'] = User::findOrFail($id);
    $data['properties'] = Property::getAllProperties();
    $data['property'] = null;
    $data['units'] = [];
    $data['unit'] = null;
    $data['rentings'] = AppHelper::RENTING_STATUS;
    $data['renting'] = 1;
    $data['cycles'] = AppHelper::BILLING_CYCLE;
    $data['cycle'] = 1;
    return view('admin.tenants.assign.form',$data);
```

I have a request $data['renting'] = $request->get('renting'); which is entered in this form but should be updated on the users table

the users table

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->enum('renting',[0,1]);
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

How do I update the users table, renting column, from AssignedUnitController

Comment: After `AssignedUnit::create`, query users table to update the required column

Comment: that is the question, how do I query and update it? I am already calling the users table on create

Comment: On which column both `users` and `assigned_units` tables are related?

Comment: yes, they are related, but users table column is what I want to update the renting status from 0 to 1

Comment: After `AssignedUnit::create`, call `User::where('id', $request->get('tenant_id'))->update(['renting' => $data['renting']);`

Comment: thanks, there's a syntax error `->update(['renting' => $data['renting']]);` and its working, thanks @Haridarshan

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry missed closing `]` bracket